# How to retreive sharepoint list items from subfolders with caml query

Tags: sharepoint, office365, caml

Using Nintex workflow, I'm able to successfully archive SharePoint list items to another list (Archival list) in Year/Month folders. That is items modified in January 2017 can be found in Archival list -> 2017 Folder ->Jan subfolder. I have another page where I can select the year and month from html drop down. I'm facing issues when i try to  retrieve the list items from the selected folder/subfolder using caml query.
Appreciate if you can guide me on this.

Answer (score 0):

Try change the scope from "Recursive" to "RecursiveAll" in your query. RecursiveAll gets all files and all folders under the specified location.

See source: https://community.nintex.com/thread/14092-query-list-with-folders-and-items

Comment: Thanks @Robin. I will surely try this out.